# Retrofit2. В ответ на запрос все данные = null

Tags: android, retrofit2

Доброго времени суток. 
Столкнулся со следующей проблемой - в ответ на запрос получаю: response.message() = ok, но в теле ответа пусто:  response.body().getLeads() = null, response.body().getServerTime() = null;

Может, кто-то видит где ошибка??

```
public interface MyRequest {
@GET("/private/api/v2/json/leads/list?USER_LOGIN=alex1987dev%40gmail.com&USER_HASH=0fd1aef9865f25175df4e4a50dacc4c0")
Call<Response> fetchJSON();
```

}

Запрос

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://new5a17c6ed35374.amocrm.ru")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    MyRequest myRequest = retrofit.create(MyRequest.class);
    Call<Response> call = myRequest.fetchJSON();
    call.enqueue(this);
```

Классы для JSON:

```
public class Response {

@SerializedName("leads")
@Expose
List<Lead> leads;
@SerializedName("server_time")
@Expose
private Integer serverTime;

public Response(List<Lead> leads, Integer serverTime) {
    this.leads = leads;
    this.serverTime = serverTime;
}

public List<Lead> getLeads() {
    return leads;
}

public void setLeads(List<Lead> leads) {
    this.leads = leads;
}

public Integer getServerTime() {
    return serverTime;
}

public void setServerTime(Integer serverTime) {
    this.serverTime = serverTime;
}
```

}

```
public class Lead {
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("last_modified")
@Expose
private Integer lastModified;
@SerializedName("status_id")
@Expose
private String statusId;
@SerializedName("price")
@Expose
private String price;
@SerializedName("linked_company_id")
@Expose
private String linkedCompanyId;
@SerializedName("responsible_user_id")
@Expose
private String responsibleUserId;
@SerializedName("pipeline_id")
@Expose
private Integer pipelineId;
@SerializedName("closest_task")
@Expose
private Integer closestTask;
@SerializedName("main_contact_id")
@Expose
private Integer mainContactId;
@SerializedName("tags")
@Expose
private List<Tag> tags = null;
@SerializedName("date_create")
@Expose
private Integer dateCreate;
@SerializedName("account_id")
@Expose
private String accountId;
@SerializedName("created_user_id")
@Expose
private String createdUserId;
@SerializedName("custom_fields")
@Expose
private List<CustomField> customFields = null;
@SerializedName("date_close")
@Expose
private Integer dateClose;

public Lead(String id, String name, Integer lastModified, String statusId, String price,
            String linkedCompanyId, String responsibleUserId, Integer pipelineId,
            Integer closestTask, Integer mainContactId, List<Tag> tags, Integer dateCreate,
            String accountId, String createdUserId, List<CustomField> customFields, Integer dateClose) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.lastModified = lastModified;
    this.statusId = statusId;
    this.price = price;
    this.linkedCompanyId = linkedCompanyId;
    this.responsibleUserId = responsibleUserId;
    this.pipelineId = pipelineId;
    this.closestTask = closestTask;
    this.mainContactId = mainContactId;
    this.tags = tags;
    this.dateCreate = dateCreate;
    this.accountId = accountId;
    this.createdUserId = createdUserId;
    this.customFields = customFields;
    this.dateClose = dateClose;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Integer getLastModified() {
    return lastModified;
}

public void setLastModified(Integer lastModified) {
    this.lastModified = lastModified;
}

public String getStatusId() {
    return statusId;
}

public void setStatusId(String statusId) {
    this.statusId = statusId;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getLinkedCompanyId() {
    return linkedCompanyId;
}

public void setLinkedCompanyId(String linkedCompanyId) {
    this.linkedCompanyId = linkedCompanyId;
}

public String getResponsibleUserId() {
    return responsibleUserId;
}

public void setResponsibleUserId(String responsibleUserId) {
    this.responsibleUserId = responsibleUserId;
}

public Integer getPipelineId() {
    return pipelineId;
}

public void setPipelineId(Integer pipelineId) {
    this.pipelineId = pipelineId;
}
public Integer getClosestTask() {
    return closestTask;
}
public void setClosestTask(Integer closestTask) {
    this.closestTask = closestTask;
}
public Integer getMainContactId() {
    return mainContactId;
}
public void setMainContactId(Integer mainContactId) {
    this.mainContactId = mainContactId;
}
public List<Tag> getTags() {
    return tags;
}
public void setTags(List<Tag> tags) {
    this.tags = tags;
}
public Integer getDateCreate() {
    return dateCreate;
}
public void setDateCreate(Integer dateCreate) {
    this.dateCreate = dateCreate;
}
public String getAccountId() {
    return accountId;
}
public void setAccountId(String accountId) {
    this.accountId = accountId;
}

public String getCreatedUserId() {
    return createdUserId;
}

public void setCreatedUserId(String createdUserId) {
    this.createdUserId = createdUserId;
}

public List<CustomField> getCustomFields() {
    return customFields;
}

public void setCustomFields(List<CustomField> customFields) {
    this.customFields = customFields;
}

public Integer getDateClose() {
    return dateClose;
}

public void setDateClose(Integer dateClose) {
    this.dateClose = dateClose;
}
```

}

Сам JSON:

```
    "response":  {
  "leads":  [
  {
    "id":  "3601622",
    "name":  "Research new technologies",
    "last_modified":  1374656336,
    "status_id":  "7046196",
    "price":  "500000",
    "linked_company_id": "5279159",
    "responsible_user_id":  "103586",
    "pipeline_id":  590269,
    "closest_task": 1498199067,
    "main_contact_id": 1456323,
    "tags":[
      {
       "id":  "960472",
       "name":  "USA"},
      {
       "id":  "960854",
       "name":  "Lead"
      }
    ],
    "date_create": 1386014400,
    "account_id":  "7046192",
    "created_user_id": "4502311",
    "custom_fields":  [
      {
      "id":  "484604",
      "name":  "field",
      "values":  [
        {
          "value":  "text"
        }
      ]
    }
    ],
    "date_close": 1386018800
  }
  ],
  "server_time":  1374839787
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У Вас не совсем верная структура получилась. Попробуйте так:

```
public class ResponseContainer {
    private Response response;

    public Response getResponse() {
        return response;
    }
}
```

И затем:

```
Call<ResponseContainer> call = myRequest.fetchJSON();
```